# DD-WRT (WRT54G) and (THOMSON TG782) how to put them togather?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, dd-wrt, adsl-router

Ok so let me explain, i bought **WRT54G** and successfully installed *DD-WRT v24-sp1 (07/26/08) mini-special - build 9994*. That's all ok no problems with it all normal functioning. And just to add *(i don't need wireless, wireless is turned off always)*

What i want:
ISP's router (**TG782**) from it's INTERNET port(out) cable "which was before in my pc" is connected to **WRT54G**'s INTERNET port and then from **WRT54G** LAN port 1 to my pc.

The problem:
How do i connect and setup all? I have tried many times on many different ways but cant get it to work IF THE CABLE FROM **TG782** IS CONNECTED TO **WRT54G** ON **INTERNET PORT**.

If i connect the **TG782** to Lan port 1 on **WRT54G** and my pc to lan port 2 then all works fine after i setup gateway and all. But i want to connect **TG782** to Internet port of **WRT54G** because i need "*Access Restrictions*" and this only goes through **WAN** right? please correct me if i am wrong.

What i have tried:
This is how i have tried to setup all. The **TG782** router ip is 192.168.1.1
And **WRT54G** ip is 192.168.1.30 so in **WRT54G** control panel i have setup like this:
*----WAN Connection Type----*
**Connection Type:** Automatic Configuration - DHCP
**STP:** Disabled
*----Router IP----*
**Local IP Address:** 192.168.1.30
**Subnet Mask:** 255.255.255.0
**Gateway:** 192.168.1.1 (the **TG782**)
*----Network Address Server Settings (DHCP)----*
**DHCP Type:** DHCP Server
**Start IP Address:** 192.168.1.100
**Maximum DHCP Users:** 6

And this wont work i probably miss something more, if anyone can help i would be thankfull. Also i have to note that i have tried to set my network adapter on pc to use the gateway of **WRT54G** and ip 192.168.1.102

In short: i cant get it to work normal only as a switch!

Thanks for any help!

**-------EDIT:-------**

Here is an image which maybe can help: http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4227/allin1w.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED IT**

**Upgraded to:** DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) std - build 13064

**Main router from ISP:**
IP: 192.168.1.1
Range: 1.100 to 1.200

**WRT54G:**
---WAN Setup---
WAN Connection Type: Static IP:
WAN IP Address: 192.168.1.102
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
---Network Setup---
Router IP: 192.168.2.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1

I have tried that even before but wasnt working with old firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Make the subnet between the TG782 and the WRT54G different than what's on the LAN side of the WRT54G.

Ie: If the DHCP server on the TG is handing out 192.168.1.X (255.255.255.0), then have the DHCP server on the WRT hand out something like 192.168.2.X (255.255.255.0).

If the network (segments) are the same on both sides of the WRT router it may be confused on how to route traffic, as it's expecting to find a different network on each side.

Comment: i tried this also, have found something what you describe http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Access_To_Modem_Configuration but again no help, please take a look to image i have added in question. Thanks